How to do same header for the index route and all marketing routes without copy past Remix-flat-routes
everybody, help me out here, please. I can't figure out how to make different headers for 2 kinds of paths and index route. I don't want to add the required header in the _index folder in the route file again. But I don't want to add it in the root file either, because then it will be on all paths.  I know that the way I want to do it was done in the first version of remix using __app syntax and creating an app.jsx file with an outlet inside it, but now it doesn't work like that. how to do the same thing in remix-flat-routes
index folder and index route
all routes
layout with the header that i need to share in index route
header that i use to auth

You can add a pathless layout using hybrid routing. All child routes in the _app+ folder will get the custom <Header>
app/routes
└── _app+
    ├── _index.tsx
    ├── _layout.tsx
    └── another-route.tsx

// app/routes/_app+/_layout.tsx
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}


It's not so much a reserved name. You can use any name. The _ prefix makes it a path less layout. And the + suffix is hybrid routing which allows you to use folders for nesting.
